# Разпарсить из поля строку, сравнить её значения и записать результат сравнения в другое поле

Tags: mysql

Есть база данных футбольных матчей с результатами. Например:

```
------------------------------------------
|team      | team2   | score | add_score |
------------------------------------------
|ManUnited | Chelsia |2:1    |           |
------------------------------------------
|Arsenal   | Everton |1:1    |           |
------------------------------------------
|StockCity |Liverpool|1:3    |           |
------------------------------------------
```

Следует в поле add_score записать результат: win1, win2 или draw в зависимости от результата.
Предполагаю, что можно использовать регулярное выражение - брать первую цифру, брать вторую цифру и сравнивать их, но как это закодить - не знаю. Помогите написать запрос сравнивающий цифры и записывающий в другое поле результат сравнения.

Comment: `substring_index` проще выделить значения. А вообще надо бы подумать над пересмотром структуры БД, SQL не предназначен для работы с данными лежащими в одном поле через разделители

Comment: это упрощенный вариант, может ещё такое быть, когда надо учитывать результат первого тайма, а там уже вариантов результатов намного больше и без сравнения не разобраться

Comment: функций получения подстроки по регулярному выражению в MySQL все равно нет, так что только строковыми функциями

Comment: @Mike *функций получения подстроки по регулярному выражению в MySQL все равно нет* Смотря какая у автора версия сервера... в 8+ имеется REGEXP_SUBSTR().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE cal
SET dop_score = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(score, ':', 1) > SUBSTRING_INDEX(score, ':', -1)
                          THEN 'win1'
                     WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(score, ':', 1) < SUBSTRING_INDEX(score, ':', -1)
                          THEN 'win2'
                          ELSE 'draw'
                END
WHERE dop_score IS NULL -- зачем менять уже заполненное?
  AND LOCATE(':', score) -- а вдруг счёт ещё не заполнен?
```

Comment: Да, верно. думаю так и нужно, цепляться на ':' и парсить по нему уже счета

Comment: @Vfvtnjd Вообще-то нет. Без дополнительных ограничений таблицы (а MySQL игнорирует CHECK clause) в поле `score` может попасть любая ахинея, ну и результат расчёта будет соответствующим... т.е. по-хорошему надо усложнить проверку, и вместо простoго LOCATE использовать соотв регэксп.

Answer (score 0):

Написал запрос:

```
UPDATE `cal` SET dop_score = "win1" WHERE
 CONVERT( SUBSTRING(score, 1, 1), SIGNED ) > CONVERT( SUBSTRING(score, 3, 1), SIGNED )
```

Comment: Ну-ну... а если 5:10?